# Getting dir from .txt file

Tags: c#, installation, dir

I want to get a install dir from .txt file to use it in c# Visual Studio 2015, how can i do this ?

I have an updater and i want that he going get a installation dir from a .txt file
example: if in .txt file "c:\install\here\" then my updater going to download there files

Comment: Please add more details...

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean by "get a install dir from .txt file"

Comment: Do u need to read a string from a text file?

Comment: I have an updater and i want that he going get a installation dir from a .txt file example: if in .txt file "c:\install\here\" then my updater going to download there files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string dir="";
using(StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("FileToGetDirFrom.txt")
{
  dir=sr.ReadLine();
}
```